# Laravel routing POST method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have resource routing as:

```
Route::resource('special', 'SpecialController');
```

And HTML form:

```
 <?=Form::open(array('route' => 'special.store',  'novalidate' => "novalidate", 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true))?>
```

When I submit form I get notification:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

And URL after submit is:

```
/specials/create
```

Why form is submitted to URL `specials`?

Comment: Run `php artisan route:clear` command. If it will not help, please post result of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: I get error when I try to use artisan: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$'`

Comment: This means you have an error somewhere. You should find it, fit ix and run commands like I said before.

Comment: Try changing `<?= Form(...) ?>` to `{!! Form(...) !!}`

Comment: Tried, nothing changes

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using ? If Laravel 5.2 take a look at this [Implicit controller routes using Route::controller have been deprecated. Please use explicit route registration in your routes file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.2-deprecations)

Comment: What is your view name of the HTML that you write. is the file name something.blade.php ?

Comment: Firstly why don't you create normal form and then add action with route? It will look more cleaner. Secondly you should provide your full routes, because it looks like `/specials/create` is not defined.